# AWS Cognito credentialsProvider.login always shows NIL (SWIFT)

Tags: swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to implement Facebook Login with AWS Cognito.
After receiving the access token from Facebook, I'm not able to update the credentials provider.

```
let token = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString
credentialsProvider.logins = [AWSCognitoLoginProviderKey.Facebook.rawValue: token]
```

After this, if I print `[AWSCognitoLoginProviderKey.Facebook.rawValue: token]` I get the long string but if I print `credentialsProvider.logins` I get `NIL`.

As a result, my identity pool always shows the user as unauthenticated even after logging in with Facebook.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the latest AWS iOS SDK? If yes, then credentialProvider.logins will always be NIL and will cause your app to create unauthenticated identities.

We are in process of updating our documentation for this but essentially this is what you need to do.

Use [this constructor](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Classes/AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider.html#//api/name/initWithRegionType:identityPoolId:identityProviderManager:) to create the credentials provider. The *identityProviderManager* here should be an implementation of [AWSIdentityProviderManager Protocol](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Protocols/AWSIdentityProviderManager.html#//api/name/logins) and the *logins* method should return the dictionary mapping for your provider name to the token. The credentials provider will call this method every time it needs the identity provider token.

Comment: Is there any documentation on how to create the AWSIdentityProviderManager and how to add the dictionary mapping to the logins for Swift?

Comment: Hi sorry I've tried the construct as you said .. still not able to change unauthenticated user to authenticated   `code  let ip = AWSIdentityProviderManager?.init() ;
            ip?.logins().setValue(token, forKey: "graph.facebook.com") `

Comment: The logins are not supposed to be set in the managers. The logins method should return a valid dictionary of provered name as key and token as value. Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37146730/3204480) for more details.