# Finding a user ID, using AWS / iOS

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, authentication

I am starting to find my way around using AWS.
But I have a simple question for which I have not found an answer by searching the net an trying what came to my mind. Here is the relevant working code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ...

    if AWSSignInManager.sharedInstance().isLoggedIn {
        print("We are already logged in!")
        // I would like to display the user identification of the current user.
    }

    ...
}
```

At the place of the comment I would like to print the user ID of the current user (when someone is logged in).
I presume there has to be a way. How can I do that?

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50988499/aws-cognito-sign-in-not-working-swift-ios

Comment: Yes indeed that's already an improvement. I am not totally sure this is what I should consider as a user ID though. Using the code in the post I can get: AccessKey, SecretKey and a SessionKey. Because that seems to change every time I launch the app.

Comment: Looking a bit more into the link mentioned by Dharmesh, seems to indicate that I should be able to get more than AccessKey, SecretKey and a SessionKey (contrary to what I fisrt thought). But I would like to find something simpler (if possible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe consider the Cognito "username" field, which is the unique ID (immutable) for each user:

```swift
        let amc = AWSMobileClient.sharedInstance();
        if (amc.isSignedIn) {
             print ("Signed in with username=\(amc.username!)")
        }
```

we can also use `getUserAttributes` to fetch all the attributes like so:

```
            // See all the attributes the user has
            amc.getUserAttributes { (attributes, error) in
                if let attributes = attributes {
                    for (key, value) in attributes {
                        print("\(key): \(value)")
                    }
                } else if let error = error {
                    print("Unexpected error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thanks, the first part of your suggestion does not seem very promising as far as I can see. Following what happens under the debugger, I see this: (lldb) p amc.isSignedIn
(Bool) $R10 = false
(lldb) p amc.username
(String?) $R12 = "myuserguy"
 The username is correct but surprisingly isSignedIn appears as false.

Comment: Fortunately the second part sounds better. I get these attributes:
ATTRIBUTE :: phone_number_verified: false
ATTRIBUTE :: email_verified: true
ATTRIBUTE :: email: cwn52510@cndps.com
ATTRIBUTE :: sub: a2bz6zc3-xyzt-1234-809f-51214f736a80
ATTRIBUTE :: phone_number: +839022331234

It seems like the 4th attribute called "sub" could be what I need.

Comment: I can indeed retrieve this number for the given user in the AWS console.

Comment: oh, the first part might be a bug in the aws sdk: https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-ios/issues/1314

Answer (score 0):

I believe the userId you are looking for is `AWSMobileClient.default().getIdentityId()`

https://aws-amplify.github.io/aws-sdk-ios/docs/reference/AWSMobileClient/Classes/AWSMobileClient.html#/c:@CM@AWSMobileClient@objc(cs)AWSMobileClient(im)getIdentityId